# Find column index (col names) where row value is equal to zero (R)

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column called "Index" in the dataframe "NA_perc_by_asset" with a string that is the concatenation of all columns for which a specific row (asset) is equal to zero. 1) First solution:

```
NA_perc_by_asset$Index=apply(NA_perc_by_asset, 1, function(i) paste(names(i[i == 0 ]), collapse = ', '))
```

Error:
The results of 1) seems to just give me the exact match of row = to 0

[image: result of 1)]

Here you can see that for each row the function write just the col "GLOBAL_ALL" and I would like other col names for which row =0, for instance col "GLOBAL_HEAD" and others.
Maybe is matter to use the function round() or is matter of string/numeric formatting issues.

Here you can see a piece of table:

[image: sample of the table]

Or with this code: 2) Using `paste()`:

```
NA_perc_by_asset$Index2=NA_perc_by_asset[ , paste_column  := paste( names( 
NA_perc_by_asset[,colMeans(NA_perc_by_asset==0)==T] ), collapse = ', ') ]
```

Error:

```
Error in `:=`(paste_column, paste(names(NA_perc_by_asset[, colMeans(NA_perc_by_asset ==  : 
Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, 
once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Please someone can provide me a solution?

thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't post data as pictures. See also: [*How to make a great R reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution in base R:

```
ci <- col(df)[df == 0]
ri <- row(df)[df == 0]
ta <- tapply(names(df)[ci], ri, FUN = toString)

df[names(ta), "index"] <- ta
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>   x y index
> 1 1 2  <NA>
> 2 0 3     x
> 3 2 0     y
> 4 0 0  x, y
> ```

---

Used example data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,0,2,0), y = c(2,3,0,0))
```